# Warning for ternary conditional operator only occurs at local scope

Tags: swift, struct, initialization, conditional-operator

I use the following Swift code to set a key string depending on the units value:

```
let units = 0
let key = units == 0 ? "F" : "C"
// this example makes key = "F"
```

The above example works as it should with no warnings when it is in the global scope of a Swift file. However, when I place the same code into an initializer or in a function, I receive a warning referring to the "C" term:

```
struct Almanac {
    // properties
}

extension Almanac {

    init?(json: [String: Any]) {
        let units = 0
        let key = units == 0 ? "F" : "C"  // WARNING: Will never be executed

        // ...
    }

}

func logunits() {
    let units = 0
    let key = units == 0 ? "F" : "C"  // WARNING: Will never be executed
    print("key is \(key)")
}
```

Why does this warning only appear when the ternary conditional is used at the local scope?

Comment: As far as I can see, this has nothing to do with failable initialisers – you'll get the same warning if you just put the code in a function. It only doesn't give you a warning when it's at the top level of a main.swift file, or a playground (whether this is intended or not, I can't say)

Comment: @Hamish Based on your comment, I revised my question. I would still like to know why the scope of the operator causes the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to scope because in some given scope the compiler is able to resolve ths simple expression and see that some part will not be executed.

With this:

```
func logunits() {
    let units = 0
    let key = units == 0 ? "F" : "C"
    print("key is \(key)")
}
```

the compiler has `units = 0` and `units == 0 ?` in the same scope, so it is able to resolve the path (because nothing changes the value of `units` between the two lines) and tell you that yes, indeed, units is 0 and yes, "C" will always be ignored.

If you change the value:

```
func logunits() {
    let units = 1
    let key = units == 0 ? "F" : "C"
    print("key is \(key)")
}
```

The warning suddenly jumps from "C" to "F". :)

And if you put the value out of the scope:

```
let units = 0

func logunits() {
    let key = units == 0 ? "F" : "C"
    print("key is \(key)")
}
```

The warning disappears.

Note that if there's any code in the path that can change the value of `units`, even a stupid one like in this example, the warning also disappears:

```
func logunits() {
    var units = 0
    if true { units = 1 }
    let key = units == 0 ? "F" : "C"
    print("key is \(key)")
}
```

Comment: So why is it able to check the value in some contexts and not in others?

Comment: @wigging Because in some contexts it is able to see that nothing will change the value, like when it is in local scope and the two lines are consecutive. If you tell the compiler "hey this has a value of zero, oh by the way which is the value so I can choose this other thing?" it will answer "well it is zero, as you just said the line before...". If you introduce anything that can change the value, this feature stops working - because it works only if the context is 100% guarantee without mutation for the analyzed value. If the value can change at runtime, this compiler feature do not apply.

Comment: @wigging That's what I'm saying with `resolve the path`, look at your code flow: start at the function signature, then next line, then next line, then... This is the path. If static data is analyzable in the path, the compiler does compute the path. If the data can change at runtime (which is most of the code we write), it doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I understand now, thank you for the explanation.